# How should search work on the jobs site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I feel like the search functionality on the jobs site is pretty weak.  I'm curious if anyone else feels the same way and if this is the intended functionality.

For example - I just searched for `data engineer` and it seems like jobs that have a occurrences of the terms `data` and `engineer` in the *description* are given a much high priority than jobs that have that actual phrase in the title.  In this instance I had to [go to the third page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=data%20engineer&r=true&pg=3) before I found a job with `data engineer` in the title.

This doesn't seem particularly useful to me.  Especially since users can search for specific technologies by using the tag syntax (`[mongodb]` for example).  Is there a way to search and put more emphasis on the job titles?  I feel like I asked a similar question a while ago and that someone said they would be implementing some changes, though I can't seem to find that question now.  While there have been changes to the jobs site recently, they don't seem related to this type of thing.

Are people satisfied with the current jobs search functionality?  Do the results that I am seeing above seem strange to anyone else?

Comment: Its not perfect but search is always hard to get right...we use elastic search on an internal project we have here and it is a nightmare to get right.  One change or one "new feature" and you end up breaking something else.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I agree, the search engine can be made better (and we're always working on that). Between now and when we make it super duper smart, feel free to use our [advanced search parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs) to perform searches, so if you want to do phrase search, you should search for `"data engineer"`. If you want to restrict it to the title, you can do `title:"data engineer"`.

You can see that both the [regular phrase search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=%22data+engineer%22) and the [title restricted search](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&q=title%3A%22data+engineer%22) yield better results.

We should also work on making them more widely known, I didn't know of their existence until I broke them with a new feature.

Comment: Awesome - good to know thanks!  Also, sorry if my post sounded overly critical.  The jobs site is fantastic overall and you should be very proud of the work you have done!

Comment: I don't think you were critical abe. I heard about the search params a long long time ago and then recently doing searches on jobs, I expected to be able to search by tag or technology and I got a little put off. Thank you both :)

Comment: @AbeMiessler your post didn't sound critical at all ;) I'm glad you enjoy the jobs site, I will gladly take the credit I don't deserve though

Answer (score 2):

A few of us had an interesting discussion about this - definitely agree that the logic can be improved. In addition to the functionality that Gervasio noted above, we do have some changes in the works that could improve your experience here.

First - we're updating job search to support Dev Types. Basically, on our backend we categorize every job by Dev Type (e.g. Full Stack Web - you can see the current list on the Match Preferences view). So this would mean if you type "Full Stack Web" in keyword search, we'd show & prioritize jobs that are mapped to the Full Stack Web dev type. This should yield better, more accurate results than the current description search, but would need to be validated.

After laying that groundwork, we'd be able to do more interesting stuff like layer in synonyms and an extra boost for titles. So you'd get better results whether you type "Full Stack Web", "Fullstack Engineer", etc. - and jobs that match your exact keyword search would display at the top of the list.

Assuming that Data Engineer is a synonym of an existing dev type (or we create a new one?), I think this solution could help with your issue.

Comment: Very cool - looking forward to seeing it!